# django 1.6.2 : CSS not extending to child templates

Tags: python, html, css, django, http-redirect

I´m having a problem with this. I would really appreciate the help. My `base.html` has a `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`. I made a  Signup.html that looks like this:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Join now</h1>
        <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token%}
            {{form.as_p}}    
            <input type='submit' class= 'btn btn-success btn-block'>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html` has a few css links that work fine when i launch Signup.html. Then i made a `thankyou.html` that extends `base.html` in the same way `Signup.html` does :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{%static "css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet"%}"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{%static "css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet"%}"/>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{%static "css/custom.css"  rel="stylesheet"%}"/> 

{% block side %}

<h4>Thank you for joining!</h4>

{% endblock %}
```

but it is not showing any css, it´s plain HTML.

Here it is the `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),

    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^thank-you/$', 'signups.views.thankyou', name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My `views.py`:

```
from .forms import SignUpForm

def home(request):

    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit = False)
        save_it.save()
        messages.success(request, 'We will be in touch')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')     #se agrega la pagina 'than-you' asi que hay
                                                    #que agregarla en -urls.py-    

    return render_to_response("signup.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance= RequestContext(request))

def thankyou(request):

    return render_to_response("thankyou.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

My `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#Template location

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static", "templates"),
   # '/Users/user/desktop/skillshare/static/templates',
)

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS= (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static", "static"),
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS stuff in thankyou.html is not in any block. If you're extending a parent template, any actual content in your child template must be inside a block defined by the parent.

Comment: Hi. Can you show an example?. I´m sorry i´m new on this django development. Thank you.